# Android: NoClassDefFound

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I have an Android project that's using SubVersion. I've used Subclipse to import the project into my Eclipse Wordspace.

Now I have a problem with getting a:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

The class I'm trying to import is located in the same package, and it's not an activity, so I have not added it to the manifest file (though I did try with no effect).

It looks like an issue with classpath etc, but I'm not quite sure how to go about fixing this?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the error while initializing a non-activity class from one of my activities. I dont think it's a manifest issue?

Comment: Have you done typo-mistake with class_name??

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wouldn't compile if there was a typo? It seems to be happening with all of the non-activity classes when initializing/access them eg. Class class = New Class();

Comment: Just do one thing, if you are using, then open your project and PRESS **Ctrl+Shift+O**(it is not ZERO) once

Comment: thanks, however this didn't help. I've checked the .classpath file in the eclipse workspace and it seems to be correct. I'm pretty sure it's a issue with the classpath though. If imports weren't done correctly or if there was typo's I would see compile errors before being able to run it?

Comment: Try another trick, just restart your Eclipse once, then run it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16135/discussion-between-azarat-and-chintan-raghwani)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to create a new android project, copy all your files there. Then make sure your class path are correct.
Lastly, Project>Clean. Make sure you didn't import any R.

Edit:
If that doesn't work, you may want to double check you fields, static blocks.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Will be thrown if your class failed at initialize.

Comment: Thanks. I use subclipse so I tried creating a new project and checking out the files from there, and also did a clean etc, but still no luck.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything is fine. Just double checked the Class I needed to import in the activity and no typos or anything there. I've also checked that there is a myClass.class file in the bin folder. But the "make sure you class path are correct", not sure, it looks ok to me though, compared to some of my other projects it looks as it should hm.